# How to set the default of a JSONField to empty list in Django and django-jsonfield?

Tags: python, django, django-models, reference

## Question

What is the best way to set a [`JSONField`](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) to have the default value of a new list in `django`?

### Context

There is a model where one of the fields is a list of items. In the case where there are no items set, the model should have an empty list.

### Current solution

```
from django.models import Model

class MyModel(Model):
    the_list_field = JSONField(default=[])
```

Is this the best way to do it? Should it be switched to use `list` instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using Django's built-in jsonfield?

Comment: @RodXavier MySQL < 5.7 and other legacy code uses them, so for consistency.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation for JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) you should indeed use `default=list`
because using `default=[]` would create a mutable object that is shared between all instances of your field and could lead to some objects not having an empty list as a default.

Please note that this does not only apply for `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` but for all other kinds of objects and functions [in Python in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Quote from the docs:

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as list (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a list (such as a function). Incorrectly using default=[] creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of

Answer (score 58):

`list` and `dict` are callable, while `[]` and `{}` are not (you can't do `[]()`). So:

- Use **`JSONField(default=list)`** over `JSONField(default=[])`
- Use **`JSONField(default=dict)`** over `JSONField(default={})`

If you want to instantiate with some data you can do the following:

```
def jsonfield_default_value():  # This is a callable
    return [0, 0]  # Any serializable Python obj, e.g. `["A", "B"]` or `{"price": 0}`

class MyModel(Model):
    the_list_field = JSONField(default=jsonfield_default_value)
```